# How is it possible that the python program is utilizing multiple cores when running using Cpython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, gil

All documentation states that running a python program using the `threading` library does not truly enable you to run the program on multiple cores on Cpython interpreter. However, the CPU usage shows that it's utilizing multiple cores. How is that possible?

I did verify that the python interpreter was Cpython using

```
import platform
platform.python_implementation() # output-> 'Cpython'
```

Python version - 3.5.2 
OS - ubuntu

Threading code

```
import threading
import math

def fizz():
  print ("start")
  for i in range (1, 100000000):
    math.sqrt(i)

  print(" exit")

threads = []

n = 4
for _ in range (n):
  t = threading.Thread(target=fizz)
  threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
  t.start()

for t in threads:
  t.join()

print ("Done")
```

CPU usage before running program(running `top`)

```
op - 09:27:44 up 235 days, 11:41,  8 users,  load average: 0.27, 0.23, 0.13
Tasks: 530 total,   1 running, 522 sleeping,   7 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :  0.3 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  :  0.3 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

CPU usage while running program

```
op - 09:29:29 up 235 days, 11:43,  8 users,  load average: 0.39, 0.24, 0.14
Tasks: 530 total,   1 running, 522 sleeping,   7 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  : 26.0 us,  0.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 73.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.3 st
%Cpu1  : 24.5 us,  1.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 74.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.3 st
%Cpu2  : 25.0 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 74.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  : 26.1 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 73.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

Comment: are you sure that the program utilizing the multiple cores is the same that you wrote? Please check for which process is utilizing CPU also

Comment: Yes, try 3, and then 2 threads just to check it is your program using the cores.

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation means using the `threading` does not run multiple threads truly at the same time, It means you can only use one core capacity in one process, even you run 4 or 8 threads at the same time.

Comment: Hm I see. Is there any way to visualize the cpu core usage other than using the `top` command?